# MySQL command querying all MyISAM database

Tags: mysql, innodb, myisam

I would appreciate if anyone could help me of what's the proper command in MySQL to query all database for having "MyISAM" engine. I need to convert all DB & tables from MyISAM to InnoDB.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Below is the Query to find all the tables which have `MyISAM` Engine

```
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA as DbName ,TABLE_NAME as TableName ,ENGINE as Engine FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE ENGINE='MyISAM' AND TABLE_SCHEMA NOT IN('mysql','information_schema','performance_schema');
```

Above Query will list all the tables having `MyISAM` Engine.

**For how to convert your existing MyISAM tables to InnoDB**
*Below is the Query that will Return ALTER Statements to convert existing `MyISAM` Tables to `InnoDB`.*

```
SELECT CONCAT('ALTER TABLE `', TABLE_SCHEMA,'`.`',TABLE_NAME, '` ENGINE = InnoDB;') FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE ENGINE='MyISAM' AND TABLE_SCHEMA NOT IN('mysql','information_schema','performance_schema');
```

You can execute these statements to convert engines.

Comment: Thanks @AbdulManaf. I didn't expect the first command would take time on the server.

Comment: Yes,It should not take time.

Comment: How to query to find all the tables in databases that are not InnoDB?