# Update character set for all columns in entire MySQL server

Tags: mysql, character-set

I'm upgrading from MySQL 5.7 to 8.0 and right now cleaning the old stuff. I used Upgrade Checker to verify my environment. Lot's of things are cleaned now, but one of the issues I have currently is thousands of warnings for column's default character set, which is currently utf8.
I followed this: [Upgrade all MySQL columns, tables, and databases from utf8mb3 to utf8mb4](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/257962/upgrade-all-mysql-columns-tables-and-databases-from-utf8mb3-to-utf8mb4) but it fixed the tables, colums are not updated.

Is there a way to update all columns default char set to UTF8mb4 at once?

Example UC output below:

```
  jiradb.AO_60DB71_CARDCOLOR.VAL - column's default character set: utf8
  jiradb.AO_60DB71_CARDLAYOUT.FIELD_ID - column's default character set: utf8
  jiradb.AO_60DB71_CARDLAYOUT.MODE_NAME - column's default character set: utf8
  jiradb.AO_60DB71_COLUMN.NAME - column's default character set: utf8
  jiradb.AO_60DB71_COLUMNSTATUS.STATUS_ID - column's default character set: utf8
```

Comment: The referenced Q&A included `ALTER TABLE ... CONVERT TO ...` -- That is where all the varchar/text columns get converted.  Look at the queries run by that code to see if that actually happened.